# How to access kernel variables in tf.layers.conv2d?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I want to visualize weights in convolutional layers to watch how they change.

But I can not find a way to access weights in convolutional layers in `tf.layers.conv2d`

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You could access that variable by name:

```
weights = sess.run('<name_of_your_layer>/weights:0', feed_dict=...)
```

If you're unsure about the name of your variable, see what it could be by printing `tf.trainable_variables()`

Answer (score 2):

With inspiration from this: [How to get CNN kernel values in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244446/how-to-get-cnn-kernel-values-in-tensorflow)

Make sure to give it a name:

```
conv_layer = tf.layers.conv2d(..., name='YOUR_NAME', ...)
```

Access the variables like this:

```
gr = tf.get_default_graph()
conv1_kernel_val = gr.get_tensor_by_name('YOUR_NAME/kernel:0').eval()
conv1_bias_val = gr.get_tensor_by_name('YOUR_NAME/bias:0').eval()
```