# How to get Conv2D kernel values in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform

### Problem

I have a `Conv2D` layer:

```
l0 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 3, activation=None, input_shape=(36,36,3))
```

I would like to find out the exact values in the filter/kernel matrix used (*not just* the number of them). **How can I access kernel matrix values?**

---

### Solution attempt

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
```

I created a numpy array:

```
x_core = np.array([[1,0,0,1],
                   [0,0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0,0],
                   [1,0,0,1]],dtype=float)
```

Cast it to a shape `(1,4,4,1)` tensor:

```
x = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(tf.convert_to_tensor(x_core),axis=0),axis=3)
```

Apply a `Conv2D` layer to it with `strides=(2,2)`. This means that the output will be a 2 by 2 matrix, the top left value in it will be equal to the top left value in the kernel matrix, top right of the result will be equal to top right of the kernel matrix, and so on. (The particular zeros and ones in `x_core` achieve this.)

```
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 2, strides=(2,2), activation=None, input_shape=x.shape[1:])(x)
```

However, `y` changes if I rerun the code, ie the filter is not constant, suggesting that the kernel matrix is drawn from a distribution.

---

### Similar questions

Similar but different question: [How to get CNN kernel values in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244446/how-to-get-cnn-kernel-values-in-tensorflow) - this method only worked in Tensorflow 1. Problems with it:

- `gr = tf.get_default_graph()` gives `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'`
- If I replace `get_default_graph` with `Graph` (as I believe that is the newer equivalent), put `name="conv1"` to my layer definition: `conv_layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 2, strides=(2,2), activation=None, input_shape=x.shape[1:],name="conv1")` then run `conv1_kernel_val = tf.Graph().get_tensor_by_name('conv1/kernel:0').eval()` as suggested, I get:

> KeyError: "The name 'conv1/kernel:0' refers to a Tensor which does not
> exist. The operation, 'conv1/kernel', does not exist in the graph."

Comment: this might help [How to correctly get layer weights from Conv2D in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305891/how-to-correctly-get-layer-weights-from-conv2d-in-keras)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

input_shape = (4, 28, 28, 3)
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
model = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape[1:])
y = model(x)
print(model.kernel)
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why this does not work if I leave out the `y = model(x)` line?

Comment: The model is built the first time it is called